# Passing Parameters to Crystal report from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

This is my first attempt to work on Crystal report so please bear with me.

I have an ASP page, on which I have `CrystalReportViewer`. And a report is created for it, but I have to pass the values to the report fields without connecting to Database (Please don't ask why). Below is my ASP code

**ASP Code**

```
....
    <%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
    ....
     <asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" OnClick="btnPreview_Click"
                        Text="Preview" />
        ......          
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer AutoDataBind="True" Height="1202px" ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="1104px" HasCrystalLogo="True" />
......
```

**C# Code**

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
.....
  protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var crReport = new ReportDocument();
            crReport.Load(Server.MapPath("SadadReceiptCR.rpt"));

            //A Parameter Field created as static namely "red_number" in the report
            crReport.SetParameterValue("red_number", "Test Value");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReport;
            CrystalReportViewer1.ShowFirstPage();
        }
```

**The issue is that the `CrystalReportViewer` does not appear when the `btnPreview` click event and a page_load is called.**

Am I missing something (and I think I am)

**Edit:**

Ok I have done the following:

1- Uninstall the CR from windows

2- Downloaded the .exe and 'run as admin'

3- Create a new ASP project and used the 'CrystalReportViewer'

but now it gives me this error:  Any Ideas please.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the path of rpt is ok?

Comment: First I have some error in path while debugging that "File Could Not Load", but when I set the path where it is, it does not show any error.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the Crystal Report Viewer web component is installed (check in IIS under the aspnet_client folder) and that it's actually accessible from your page?

Comment: Add the report to your solution and then reference it as "~\SadadReceiptCR.rpt". Then change your your "protected void" to a "private void" and see if that works.

Comment: @StephenByrne Thanks for replying, Yes there is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13"..and to check "it's actually accessible from your page" How to check?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I changed the protected void to private void and its giving me the error that button click event is not found.

Comment: when the page loads, view source and click the links for the Viewer component CSS and JS files - see if you are getting access denied, etc. Also make sure the folder above is an actual web application.

Comment: @StephenByrne I checked in the source, it says that some "aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer" not found (404 Error). And when I actually checked that link its present there

Comment: When you installed CR for VS, did you use the exe installer or the msi installer?

Comment: @StephenByrne Just a very newbie question. Should I have to deploy my Web Application on IIS?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I user the msi installer.

Comment: You must use the exe on your dev machine. Uninstall the runtime and then reinstall using the exe.

Comment: @AbdulAziz - no you should be fine with the dev web server, the problem seems to be that the web viewer component isn't correctly installed - if you follow campagnolo_1's advice it should work.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 Thanks for the reply. But how to uninstall the CR Runtime from Windows 8??

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the CR web component. Can you check the app pool it's running under and cross-reference with the CR documentation - maybe it has to run on a specific framework or pipeline mode, make sure the app pool is not 64 bit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the runtime to integrate properly on your dev machine you must use the exe installer. Uninstall the current version of the CR runtime and reinstall using the exe installer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to uninstall the CR Runtime from Windows 8??

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 but usually you go into your Control Panel and under Programs and Features (Windows 7) you find a list of installed programs. Find the Crystal runtime, click on it and then choose uninstall.